# Access cookies set by an api using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I am doing development in reactjs on my localhost. I have an api written in nodejs deployed at https://bianca-service-dev0.cfapps.io

Using react i am calling an auth endpoint in the api to login my user. The auth endpoint returns a token to me in response body and a cookie name CSRF-TOKEN. When i try to view document.cookie i only see the cookies set by my localhost and dont see cookies set by the api.

Can I access cookies set by a different domain?

Comment: No, because you can only access cookies from your domain

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

JavaScript running in the browser can only read cookies associated with the page that the JS is running on.

Requests to other origins (if sent [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)) will include the cookies transparently though so you can still use them to access content on the origin that set them.